# does not has continuous extension of $S^1 \to S^1$ to $\Bbb{R}^2 \to S^1$

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, manifolds

Let $S^1$ be the smooth manifold then the identity map is smooth $i:S^1 \to S^1$,prove there exist not continuous extension from $i:\Bbb{R}^2 \to S^1$

I try to construct some connected set in $\Bbb{R}^2$ to $S^1$ that fail to be connected,for example removing two point that still keeps the domain connected but not in $S^1$ is my idea correct?

Comment: Have you learned about homology or the fundamental group?

Comment: If you know some algebraic topology then the extension tells us that the circle is a deformation retract of the plane, which implies that they have the same homology, but this is not true.

Comment: I know little bit about foundamental group,And I know a theorem which says that for compact smooth manifold there exist no smooth retraction from $X \to \partial X$ by the classification of one dimension compact smooth manifold.I decide to learn algebra topology rescently

Comment: That was my first though, too: removing two points $p$ and $q$ from $\mathbb R^2$ with $f(p)\neq f(q)$.  We have that $\mathbb R^2\setminus\{p,q\}$ is connected.

Comment: Oh I have read it from Munkres' topology book

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose such extension $f:\mathbb{R}^2\rightarrow S^1$, exist, $i\circ f$ is the identity, implies that $(i\circ f)_*:\pi_1(S^1)\rightarrow\pi_1(S^1)$ is the identity., we have $(i\circ f)_*=i_*\circ f_*$ and $f_*$ is constant, contradiction since $\pi_1(S^1)=\mathbb{Z}$.

Answer (score 3):

Suppose we may extend $i$ to $r$. That is $r:\mathbb{R}^2\rightarrow \mathbb{S}^1$ is such that $r|_{\mathbb{S}^1}=i$ and is continuous. So in particular, $r$ is a retraction from $\mathbb{R}^2$ to $\mathbb{S}^1$. Thus $\mathbb{S}^1$ is a retract of a simply connected space, which implies that $\mathbb{S}^1$ is simply connected. Contradiction.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose $i:\mathbb{S}^1\rightarrow \mathbb{S}^1$ is continuous map admitting a continuous extension $\tilde{i}:\mathbb{R}^2\rightarrow \mathbb{S}^1$ . Then, in particular, $\tilde{i}|_{\mathbb{S}^1}=i$. Hence, $\mathbb{S}^1$ is a retract of $\mathbb{R}^2$. However, this implies that

$0=H_1(\mathbb{R}^2)=H_1(\mathbb{R}^2,\mathbb{S}^1)\oplus H_1(\mathbb{S}^1)=H_0(\mathbb{S}^1)\oplus H_1(\mathbb{S}^1)=\mathbb{Z}^2$